# Cannot change key column names in property list xcode

Tags: xcode, list, properties, key, plist

I created a plist in xcode 6, and although I can change the values and the type. I cannot change the key. I know you can change the property list type, but I still cannot change the key even after cycling through all the property list types. I've been looking everywhere, and I cant seem to find an answer. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm dumb.. I needed to change the value of root to "Dictionary" not "array"...